# Helm always reports a 403 error when adding minio repo

Tags: kubernetes-helm, minio, helm-tls

I have run the latest version of minio with Docker and can access it normally by browser.
Then I installed the MC client and tested Minio with MC, and everything worked fine.
but when I use helm add the minio repo. I get a 403 error.

```
[root@k8smaster01 helm-charts]# mc config host list
gcs    
  URL       : https://storage.googleapis.com
  AccessKey : YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-HERE
  SecretKey : YOUR-SECRET-KEY-HERE
  API       : S3v2
  Lookup    : dns

local  
  URL       : http://localhost:9000
  AccessKey : 
  SecretKey : 
  API       : 
  Lookup    : auto

myminio
  URL       : http://172.16.5.182:9000
  AccessKey : minioadmin
  SecretKey : minioadmin
  API       : s3v4
  Lookup    : auto

play   
  URL       : https://play.min.io
  AccessKey : Q3AM3UQ867SPQQA43P2F
  SecretKey : zuf+tfteSlswRu7BJ86wekitnifILbZam1KYY3TG
  API       : S3v4
  Lookup    : auto

s3     
  URL       : https://s3.amazonaws.com
  AccessKey : YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-HERE
  SecretKey : YOUR-SECRET-KEY-HERE
  API       : S3v4
  Lookup    : dns

[root@k8smaster01 helm-charts]# mc ls myminio
[2020-06-16 18:10:01 CST]      0B minio-helm-repo/
[root@k8smaster01 helm-charts]# mc ls myminio/minio-helm-repo/
\[2020-06-16 18:17:20 CST]     76B index.yaml
[root@k8smaster01 helm-charts]# helm repo add minio-test-repo http://172.16.5.182:9000/minio-helm-repo
Error: looks like "http://172.16.5.182:9000/minio-helm-repo" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch http://172.16.5.182:9000/minio-helm-repo/index.yaml : 403 Forbidden
[root@k8smaster01 helm-charts]#
[root@k8smaster01 helm-charts]# helm repo add minio-test-repo http://172.16.5.182:9000/minio-helm-repo --username minioadmin --password minioadmin
Error: looks like "http://172.16.5.182:9000/minio-helm-repo" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch http://172.16.5.182:9000/minio-helm-repo/index.yaml : 400 Bad Request
[root@k8smaster01 helm-charts]#
```

my minio version is latest（RELEASE.2020-06-14T18-32-17Z） 
my mc version is RELEASE.2020-05-28T23-43-36Z
my helm version is version.BuildInfoVersion:"v3.2.3"

how can i add the repo to helm successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> API       : s3v4

As far as I know helm can't use s3 natively, so in our scenario we used the **helm s3 plugin** wich provides s3 protocol support.

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/hypnoglow/helm-s3

Depending on your scenario, you might have to set some environment variables too, see https://github.com/hypnoglow/helm-s3/blob/master/hack/integration-tests-local.sh#L9 for more details
(Hint: S3-Endpoint URL is set via AWS_ENDPOINT ENV-variable, so be sure this is set)

After installing and configuring the plugin I was able to init and add the repo.

Be sure to init you repo
(Note that the enpoint URL is not part of the s3-url. The s3 plugin uses the AWS_ENDPOINT ENV-variable to set the endpoint URL. "test-bucket/charts" is the location of the bucket on the defined repo):

```
helm s3 init s3://test-bucket/charts
```

This is setting up the repo and adds the index.yaml

You can then add the repo

```
helm repo add repo-name s3://test-bucket/charts
```

After adding the repo you can push charts

```
helm s3 push chart.tgz repo-name
```

Also take at look at the following script, wich helped me to understand the needed steps to add, init and use the repo correctly:
https://github.com/hypnoglow/helm-s3/blob/master/hack/integration-tests.sh

Also, indexing is done automatically by the plugin when pushing
(See https://github.com/hypnoglow/helm-s3#push)